# How can I enlarge pictures one independent of the others when we click on it with VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

[link of my code](https://codepen.io/shirley_truffierblanc/pen/qMZwXv)

So When I click one of the three picture I would like my photos to enlarge. But Now in my code it is not the case, when I click on one of the three picture, these enlarge together. 
I don't know where is the problem in my code.

I can also give you a picture in order to understand better what I want to obtain.

[picture the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RdPQ.png)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

```
    <div class ="product-image">
      <img v-bind:src="image" :class="{ full: fullWidthImage }" @click="fullWidthImage = !fullWidthImage" >

      <img v-bind:src="image2" :class="{ full: fullWidthImage }" @click="fullWidthImage = !fullWidthImage" >

      <img v-bind:src="image3" :class="{ full: fullWidthImage }" @click="fullWidthImage = !fullWidthImage" >
```

Comment: your `fullWidthImage` var is the same for all the images since it is part of their parent, that's why modifyin it for one modify it for all

Comment: thank you for your help, your answer works well!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you control enlargement of all pictures by the single `Boolean`.
I've modified your code to make it work: I've turned template into cycle using `v-for` and also turned `fullWidthImage` into number indicate what image to enlarge.

template:

```
<div class="product-image">
  <img v-for="(image, index) in [image, image2, image3]" v-bind:src="image" :class="{ full: fullWidthImage === index }" @click="fullWidthImage = index" />
</div>
```

data:

`'fullWidthImage': null`

[Fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxMxxX)